# Airflow logo covering the 50% of the webpage

Tags: airflow

I have installed Github Airflow by downloading every single PyPi dependency and installing it in offline mode.

Now when I am running web-server, its giving a warning "**please make sure to build the frontend in static/ directory and then restart the server**".

I can access Airflow webpage but its distorted. Airflow logo is almost capturing the 50% page.

Can somebody please help me setting up Airflow properly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but some may find this post useful as problem descriptions is similar, and I found this post multiple times. If anyone recently (2021 July+) is encountering this issue with static files when building airflow from source on tag or various branch, this has been fixed on main branch via this:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17086

Answer (score 5):

I found solution to my problem, just in case someone else also faces same issue and searching for solution.

You need to compile assets with a script "compile_assets.sh".
But the catch is, you need to execute this script from where the Airflow is installed and not from the source location.

Comment: thanks, for ref this worked for we with the latest version: v2.2.0.dev0


In the Airflow container:



# ./airflow/www/compile_assets.sh 


# ./scripts/in_container/stop_tmux_airflow.sh


Restart Airflow with breeze


$ ./breeze start-airflow -b postgres

Comment: Looks like ./airflow/www/compile_assets.sh is removed in the newer version of airflow..

Answer (score 0):

The message  **"please make sure to build the frontend in static/ directory and then restart the server"**  is suggesting to compile the static assets.

`./airflow/www/compile_assets.sh` script was useful for this purpose but it is removed in the newer version of airflow.

In case you are using breeze, run the below command to compile the assets

```
breeze compile-www-assets
```

help on breeze is available
`breeze --help`

If you are building the package yourself then run the below command (This is present at the end of [INSTALL](https://github.com/nshetty15/airflow/blob/main/INSTALL) file)

```
python setup.py compile_assets
```

> COMPILING FRONT-END ASSETS (in case you see "Please make sure to build
> the frontend in static/ directory and then restart the server")
>
> python setup.py compile_assets